# Editing document.xml inside a .docx file

Tags: microsoft-word, source-code

I have converted a `.docx` Word document file to a `.zip` and I have accessed the internal `document.xml` file but I'm confused as to how to edit its contents. Do I need to do this via Notepad or other more specific apps? Just FYI, the actual original `.docx` is quite large (over 10,000 words) and I need to replace the internal strings of the document whilst maintaining its original readable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** edit with Notepad if you wish.

As long as your changes are syntactically correct, saving with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is okay. After you put it back into the `.zip` file and give the file its `.docx` extension, you'll have a valid Microsoft Word file.

And yes, you can edit it with a more specialized editor if you want. (You don't have to. But you can if you wish.) [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) or [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) are both okay.